# New task request on Jira

Tags: jira

I am a junior software engineer in a company and because of my current junior status, the tasks are assigned to me.

I would be happy if there is a such mechanism like "Hey supervisor, I am done with my current task, please assign me a new one"

Is there any way to request a new task from the supervisor on Jira?

Comment: Depends on JIRA's workflow, you can mark your task as done/review and post a comment on your task, ask your supervisor for new one :-)

Comment: @SalehParsa I am doing the first part already but I want to automate the second part, which you wrote "ask your supervisor for new one" :)

Comment: You as a JIRA user can't do such a thing. This is something that maybe your JIRA admin is able to do so and as far as I can say, he/she might be able to do it via creating post function in JIRA :-)

Comment: @SalehParsa I think it is an essential feature. I may think to post this as a new feature request on Jira.

Comment: Take a look at following:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/configuring-auto-assign-779158849.html and 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-automatically-assign-an-issue-to-a-user-based-on-issue-type-704413717.html

Comment: However, I did not mean auto-assign. I meant that for example, there is a button on my jira dashboard like *request for a new task*, when I click it, it asks me from who do I want to get a new task? and then, I select my supervisor from the list and my supervisor sees this request on his dashboard.

Comment: Out of the box JIRA Doesn't have this feature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was not sure if there is such a feature but I did not know it :)

Comment: No worries. Cheers

Comment: You could write a browser script that detected when you submit the particular form, which would attempt to email your boss a canned email or slack comment.

Comment: You can consider using jql to look for unassigned tasks. Go to the jql page: 
https://yourjiraurl/issues/?jql=

and run query similar to this: 
project = ABC and assignee is EMPTY

Answer (score 0):

Create a task for your supervisor to assign you a task? (Your supervisor's response may vary.)